# Взаимосвязанные Spinner Android

Tags: android, android-spinner

Необходимо, чтобы при выборе из spinnerMaterial позиции другие два спиннера  spinnerSDRMax и
spinnerSDRMin меняли свой список выдаваемых значений. Попробовал назначить setOnItemSelectedListener, но программа вылетает.

```
    // Получаем экземпляр элементов Spinner
    spinnerSDRMax = findViewById(R.id.spinner_sdrMAX);
    spinnerSDRMin = findViewById(R.id.spinner_sdrMIN);

    // Получаем экземпляр элемента Spinner Material
    spinnerMaterial = findViewById(R.id.spinner_material);
    // Настраиваем адаптер
    ArrayAdapter<?> adapterMaterial =
            ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.MaterialValues, R.layout.spinner_custom);
    adapterMaterial.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Вызываем адаптер
    spinnerMaterial.setAdapter(adapterMaterial);
    spinnerMaterial.setSelection(0);
    spinnerMaterial.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Настраиваем адаптер спиннера в зависимости от выбранного материала
            if (spinnerMaterial.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("ПЭ")) {
                ArrayAdapter<?> adapterSDRmax =
                        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(null, R.array.SDR_values_PE, R.layout.spinner_custom);
                adapterSDRmax.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                // Вызываем адаптер
                spinnerSDRMax.setAdapter(adapterSDRmax);
                spinnerSDRMax.setSelection(0);

                ArrayAdapter<?> adapterSDRMin =
                        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(null, R.array.SDR_values_PE, R.layout.spinner_custom);
                adapterSDRMin.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinnerSDRMin.setAdapter(adapterSDRMin);
                spinnerSDRMin.setSelection(8);
            } else if (spinnerMaterial.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("НПВХ")) {
                ArrayAdapter<?> adapterSDRmax =
                        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(null, R.array.SDR_values_PVCU, R.layout.spinner_custom);
                adapterSDRmax.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                // Вызываем адаптер
                spinnerSDRMax.setAdapter(adapterSDRmax);
                spinnerSDRMax.setSelection(0);

                ArrayAdapter<?> adapterSDRMin =
                        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(null, R.array.SDR_values_PVCU, R.layout.spinner_custom);
                adapterSDRMin.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinnerSDRMin.setAdapter(adapterSDRMin);
                spinnerSDRMin.setSelection(1);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: попробуйте поменять spinnerMaterial.getSelectedItem() на parent.getItemAtPosition(position) чтобы получить выбранный элемент

Comment: Сердечное спасибо! Поменял еще context c null на getApplicationContext()